# Excel Query to compare data

Tags: excel

I am new to writing queries in MS-Excel and need some help to understand if we can do something like the following to compare data between two columns:

[image]

Column A and Column B are the input values. 'p1-critical' maps to 1, 'p2-important' maps to 2 and 'p3-medium' maps to 3. If there are any change in these mapping values, I should be able to display 'false', else 'true'.

Thanks.

Comment: use the if function, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a cheeky way of doing it with an "IF" statement assuming that the rule is always the same for the number part of the text in ColumnA:

=IF(MID(A1, 2,1)=TEXT(B1,"#"), TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: yes thank you. Sorry if i was not clear in the question, I  have edited it now. I am looking for something like - a single query which i can make sure that always P1-critical values maps to 1, P2-important maps to 2 and p3-medium maps to 3. 

Not sure if its valid query for "IF Function"

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Try posting a screen grab of your Excel sheet showing more example of what the data looks like, and then an example in a couple of cases of what you want the output to be in Excel after the processing.